# Ubuntu 12.04 boot problem not starting desktop and login screen

Tags: 12.04, wubi

I had installed ubuntu 12.04 through wubi (with windows7) about an year ago. It was working fine till yesterday Aug 10th, 2014. But when I tried today booting Ubuntu, two erros appear first:

```
hd[0,0]: no wubildr
hd[0,1]: 'perfix' is not set
```

(Although these errors appeared even before but I was able to see my desktop), after then, a purple screen appeared for 4-5 seconds, then "Ubuntu" symbol appears and then blank screen. I tried to fix it by command-line (bcoz it is working fine with command line using login name and password) using 'startx' command, But it failed and showed some information which included words like 'fatal error: no scrren found' and other like that.
What should I do to fix it ?
When I used ubuntu last time, I had installed 'wine' and through it, Notepad++ was installed. May be it occuring problem.